# Battle of the sites - cancelled

Tags: discussion

> In response to the community's feedback on this contest, **we've decided
>   to cancel it.** We never intended to favor quantity over quality, but we
>   can see how this contest missed the mark. We appreciate all the
>   constructive criticism regarding this idea.
>
> In case you haven't seen the contest yet and are interested, you can
>   still read the announcement below.

As more and more research-oriented sites pop up on Stack Exchange, we can’t help but be impressed with the amazing academic resource our users have created. We also can’t help but wonder... which academic community has the most Stack spirit? In an epic question-asking battle, would Math take down Statistics? Could Linguistics edge out English? If only there was a way to find out...

Oh wait! There is: an epic question-asking battle. Let’s do it! It’s getting close to the holidays after all, so now is a perfect time for us to say thank you by continuing our tradition of giving back. As such, the community that wins this battle will get 1000 USD to donate to a charity of their choice. Winners of each round will also get 100 USD to donate to charity.

Here’s how the battle will work:

- Participating sites are English, Math, Statistics, Theoretical Computer Science, Linguistics, Physics, Philosophy, and History.
- Each round will last a week, and the contest will be single-elimination bracket-style.
- To move on to the next round, the average number of questions each site asks per day during the round must exceed that site’s current average. Whichever site exceeds their average by more questions wins the round.
- To determine who would face off in the first round, we seeded the sites according to past activity.

Are you ready for this?! Here it is:

[image]

A few more notes:

- Although this is a contest, a “Battle of the Sites” if you will, it’s all in the spirit of fundraising for charity and having fun. So while we understand (and encourage!) competitiveness, try to keep it friendly.
- While we expect this contest to generate a lot of new questions, we
  have full faith in the community’s ability to uphold its standards
  and preference for good questions. If we find that a site is getting
  a lot of bad questions during the contest, it will have to be
  disqualified.

Round one starts now and ends Sunday 11/20 at 11:59 pm UTC. Ready. Set. *GO.*

Comment: What has happened to your Psi?

Comment: @mbq check out [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110963/did-everyone-on-chaos-get-fired-or-something-what-happened-to-their-pitchforks) for an explanation.

Comment: The 8 meta questions: [Math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3212) [History](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/q/125) [Physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/965) [CSTheory](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1422) [Stats](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1003) [Philosophy](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/263) [English](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2156) [Linguistics](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/207)

Answer (score 13):

I doubt this is a good idea -- CV is about good questions and clever answers, not any virtual SE spirit measured in raw bytes of content.

The form of the battle also doesn't seem right -- it is comparing incomparable based on irrelevant factor. If you really think there is enough of wild desire for doing charity by activity on CV, there are certainly better ways to harness it --  for instance promoting answering of unanswered questions.

Comment: Agreed on all points.  This contest is not right for these sites.  And judging by the responses, our "#1 seed" is not on board at all.